# SQL Linked Server Permission Scheme

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I want to create a Linked Server between two SQL Server DBs.  However, I want to control access to this linked server to specific views.

That is, I want access to the Linked Server to be view object, not userid.

Is this possible?

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). You will, however, need to clarify what you desire.

Comment: How can this be off topic when the tags are sql-server and linked-server?